# Regex (or techniques) to guess artist from full song title?

Tags: javascript, regex

What regex (or other technique) would help calculate or 'best-guess' the **artist** in a fairly unpredictable full song title;

e.g. find `Dr Dre` from the following song title (examples from youtube):

```
Xxplosive - Dr. Dre
Dr Dre - Xxplosive
Dr Dre- Xxplosive (lyrics)
Dr. Dre - 05 - The Chronic - Nuthin' But AG Thang
```

My aim is find the most likely 2 or 3 matches, which I intend to send to an existing API which should determine the correct artist.

Comment: So, if you get 2 outputs from those 5 inputs, that would be fine?  For example, "Xxplosive" and "Dr. Dre" as outputs, where we don't know which is the artist.

Comment: The only way you could make that work with the data you've provided is if you always know the artist string, in which case you can just use the name itself as the regex.

Comment: I don't think there is any regex in the world that can help you guess what word represents a name in a sentence... not even with standard names, let alone all the random pseudonames people come up with for music artists these days...

Comment: @MatthewAbbott I'm not looking for interpretation, I'm looking to strip out words/phrases

Comment: @samb: Regex can only help you split up the track names into substrings, which are likely to contain artist names, album names, song names and track numbers. For deciding which of the substring is the artist's name you can only guess. Or apply some kind of heuristic, such as: "most of the time the pattern is `<artist> - <album> - <title>`" (or similar), hence assume the first substring to be the artist (would have a success rate of 75% for your sample data). Simple String comparison won't do much help here though, as the Youtube folks usually ain't among the more literate. Ergo: fuzzy matching

Comment: Yep, but I can send those guesses to an API (e.g. spotify/lastfm), use artist search methods and with an algorithm I can produce a much more accurate guess. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Split the song title up using some regex like `/\s*-\s*`, which would turn "`Dr Dre - Xxplosive`" into an array like: {`Dr Dre`, `Xxplosive`}.

Then match the search term `Dr. Dre` against your split segments using either:

- [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) (`O(log(n))`, probably best fit for you)
- [Metaphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone) (`O(1)`, probably good fit, moderate potential for false positives)
- [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) (`O(1)`, probably good fit, high potential for false positives)

If your list of tracks is huge, use a [BKTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BK-tree).

In other words, use either [fuzzy/approximate string matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) or [phonetic string matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_string_matching).

Protip: Use a levenshtein limit relative to the length of your search term (the longer the string, the higher the limit).

Answer (score 1):

why must you use a regex?

wouldn't just using simple string splitting work? you could just split the string by the dash, trim it and send each bit to the API. you could then use a distance based string proximity algorithm to see which bit of the song title is most likely the artist

Comment: yeah thats sort of what i'm looking for, my use of the word regex here isn't totally strict